# Performing a computation from the view

Tags: grails

From the Grails controller function if i want to retrieve a value from another object, i retrieve it as follows:

```
def person = Person.get(10)
println person.name
```

The above code will return a person object where the `ID` is `10`, and also it will return the `name` of that particular user.

Likewise, how can i do such a computation in the view.

**View**

```
<body>
<table>
<g:each in="${personInstanceList}" status="i" var="personInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td><g:link action="classesoffered"
                                url="${fieldValue(bean: personInstance, field: "id")}"
                                id="${personInstance.id}"  >
                ${personInstance.id}
                            </g:link></td>
                   .....



   ... </body>
```

The above code will display the ID of the person Object. Is it possible for me to use this ID to retrieve a value of another object. For example.

```
def school = School.get(${personInstance.id})
```

Can i use the ID `(${personInstance.id})` in order to retrieve the school from the View ?

Note: Hope i have explained the question properly. In a nutshell I want to do a computation at the view. To retrieve `schoolinstance` from `${personInstance.id}` from the view.

UPDATE

Person MODEL

```
String name
int school
```

School MODEL

```
String nameOfSchool
```

Comment: What does your `Person` class look like? The more normal Grails approach would be to have an association linking `Person` to `School` so you can just use `personInstance.school` at the appropriate places.

Comment: I have updated my post. I use School as an Integer. In that case how can i display the name of the school from the VIew ?

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal association (`School school` instead of `int school`)?  Then `personInstance.school` would give you a reference to the `School` object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a domain in your view with: (first line of the gsp)

```
<%@ page import="com.yourPackage.School" %>
```

And then, you can use the tag [set](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/set.html) to create a new variable inside you view.

For example:

```
<g:set var="school" value="${ School.get(personInstance.id) }" />
```

If you want to print the value in your GSP (for example the name of the school), you can use:

```
${ school.nameOfSchool }
```

(if school is not null of course)

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok now, how can i print the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do this kind of thing within the view, you should redesign your domain model to fit the task.  If you want each `Person` to be linked to their `School` then you should do it with a proper association rather than storing an ID (for which, incidentally, you're using the wrong type - by default the ID of a Grails domain class is a `Long`, not an `int`):

```
class Person {
  String name
  School school
}

class School {
  String name
}
```

and create instances like this:

```
// create a new school
def school = new School(name:'Example school')
// or fetch an existing one from the DB
// def school = School.get(1)

def person = new Person(name:'Illep', school:school)
```

With this model, the GSP can access the school name simply as

```
${personInstance.school?.name}
```

Comment: I agree with you. My solution answered the problem but there is probably a modeling issue.